# PLSQL - Error in associative array

Tags: oracle, plsql, associative-array

Im trying to delete a set of tables and afterwards I want to recreate them using `as select from`. For couriousity I wanted to do this with an associative array. Unfortunately something is messed up, several errors appear and I can't find the reasons. This is the code:

```
DECLARE
TYPE t_tbl
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
  L_Tbl T_Tbl;
  l_key VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  l_tbl('tableA') := 'table1';
  l_tbl('tableB') := 'table2';
  L_Tbl('tableC') := 'table3';
  l_tbl('tableD') := 'table4';

  l_key := l_tbl.first;
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      EXIT WHEN L_Key IS NULL;
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Dropping TABLE '|| L_Key ||);
      EXECUTE Immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || L_Key;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_key ||' '|| l_tbl(l_key));
    -- Catch exception if table does not exist
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
        Raise;
      END IF;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table schema1.' ||l_key||' as select * from schema2.'||l_tbl(l_key)||;
      l_key := l_tbl.next(l_key);
    END LOOP;
  End;
END;
```

I get these errors:

```
ORA-06550: line 17, column 56:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev sum
   variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date
   <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an alternatively-quoted SQL
ORA-06550: line 26, column 102:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev su
ORA-06550: line 29, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   loop
The symbol "loop" was substituted for ";" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Could someone give me a hint please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dropping a table first then trying to recreate seems backwards. Do you mean to  create b as select * from a;  drop table a; ???

Comment: 1. DROP TABLE tableA; 2. CREATE TABLE tableA AS SELECT * FROM table1;

Comment: Please post the errors you get when you run this

Comment: Updated my post with the errors i get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some unterminated append operations || on lines:

```
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Dropping TABLE '|| L_Key ||);
```

And

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table schema1.' ||l_key||' as select * from schema2.'||l_tbl(l_key)||;
```

Get rid of the || at the end. 
Also the way you are using LOOP is incorrect. Refer [example](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/iterate.html):

```
while elem is not null loop
    dbms_output.put_line(elem || ': ' || var_assoc_varchar(elem));
    elem := var_assoc_varchar.next(elem);   
end loop;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `||` at the end of the line in `line 17` and `line 25`.

And also ending loop before ending the block `begin....end`.  get `begin` before `loop` or get `end` before `end loop`.

```
           l_key := l_tbl.next(l_key);
      END LOOP;
  END;
```